# change bitmap size based device Android Studio

Tags: android, bitmap, drawable

In android studio the return value of this function
`BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.basictiles)` changes based on device size.

as and example

**Pixel**:

- size = 1.792.000
- height, width = 1120,400

**SM-G900F**

- size = 2.580.480
- height, width = 1344,480

I'm trying to find a way to get the same image size for every device/resolution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

put your `R.drawable.basictiles` file inside `drawable-nodpi` folder

another approach is to use `new BitmapFactory.Options()` when `decodeResource` (third param) and set [inScaled](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/BitmapFactory.Options#inScaled) param to `false`

Comment: Nice use of no dpi folder. +1 for that.

Answer (score 1):

You may want to look at:

```
BitmapFactory.decodeResource(Resources res, int id, BitmapFactory.Options opts)
```

You can find it [here](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/BitmapFactory)

Essentially you need to pass in [BitmapFactory.Options](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/BitmapFactory.Options) which can be used to control the resulting scaling, width, height etc of the `Bitmap`

```
BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
options.outHeight = ;// the height you want 
options.outWidth = ;// the width you want
BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.basictiles, options);
```